# Culture independent CSV

Tags: csv

I wonder if there is any way to generate culture neutral CSV file or at least specify data format of certian columns present in file. 
For example I generated CSV file that contains numbers with decimal separator (.), and after 
pass it to the client which is in the country where decimal separator is (,), client opens it with Excel and sees all values changed. 
Is there any way to resolve this isure, or just in this case do not use CSV file ?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is a "quoted CSV file".

That is as well as separating your values with commas you also enclose them in (usually) double quotes.

Like so:-

```
"first","second","3,00","Some other text, etc."
```

This format is quite common and supported by EXCEL.

Comment: Seems that I MUST use (,) like  separator in this case and Excel
will threat the cell like General formatted.

Comment: As it turns out Excel 2013 does not support enclosing values with the separator in double quotes anymore.

test, test, test,
a, b, "c,d"

The example will result in a 4 column row of values a b "c d"

Comment: This does not answer the question as the resulting CSV is still culture dependent.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways I came up with to avoid the decimal separator altogether:

1) Use scientific notation, so 1.25 would be: **`123E-2`**

2) Make it a formula, so 1.25 would be:  **`=125/100`**

Both pretty crappy, depending on your target audience, but at least Excel sees them as numbers and can calculate with them.

Answer (score 0):

A CSV file will be separated by commas (the 'C' in CSV) but you can output a text with any delimiter and qualifier and you'll be able to open it in Excel - you specify them in the step 2 of the import text wizard.

A common choice for situations like this is to use tabs (TSV).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Tab Separated Values, which does not vary between cultures and are supported by Microsoft Excel. Common file extensions are .tsv and .tab.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab-separated_values

Comment: FWIW this only partially solves the problem. the fields are delimited properly, but it still tries to interpret dots as a decimal or a thousands separator or a date separator depending on locale and heuristics.